# Testing in flutter when i have timer

Tags: flutter, testing, timer, delay

I have a splash screen in my flutter app and after 2 seconds it's navigate automatically to intro page, but when i wrote test for splash screen i got this problem

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown running a test:
A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed.
```

and many errors so.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
  
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'app',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: IntroPage(),
        );
      }
    }

  

  class IntroPage extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _IntroPage();
      }
    }
    
    class _IntroPage extends State<IntroPage>{
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) {
          timer.cancel();
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return LoginPage(); // go to Next Page
            },
          ));
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I use Future.delayed in stateless

Comment: why use statelessWidget?

Comment: why not? i have just an image center of screen and after 2 seconds navigate to login page